# Why YAML parsed list is interpreted as object by javascript?

Tags: javascript, yaml

This is my config.yml

```
key1:
  list: ['x', 'x', 'x']
```

And i parse this config with [yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) package.

```
import { parse } from 'yaml';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const parsed = parse(ReadFileSync('config.yml', 'utf-8'));

console.log(typeof parsed['key1']['list']) // this returning an object instead of list
```

Why typeof returning object instead of list?

Comment: `typeof [] === "object"`

Comment: Did you try actually logging the value instead of the `typeof`?

Comment: arrays are object in js. if u want to see if array use Array.isArray

Comment: Oh okay, i understand. I must have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

***Hi, we should know, parse method of YML library does convert the data to JavaScript object.***

> `typeof` is don't uses for check the data type because that has not got like that attribute.

Developers Mainly using `Array.isArray()`, which is specific function for array.

```
import { parse } from 'yaml';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';

let content = readFileSync('config.yml', 'utf-8')
const parsed = parse(content);

console.log(Array.isArray(parsed["key1"]["list"])) //! true
```